# {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint The statement has been terminated."}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

there is also a userstats table, I want a one to one relationship, but i'm getting the above error when I try and register a user.Thanks for the help!

User Table:

```
     public class User
        {
            [Key]
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public int UserStatsID { get; set; }
            public virtual UserStats UserStats { get; set; }

           }
```

Userstats Table

```
  [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }
```

RegisterDetailsController

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (user.Gender == Gender.Male )
            {
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterMale", "RegisterStats", new {id = user.ID });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterFemale", "RegisterStats", new { id = user.ID });

            }
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating your `UserStats`? In the code provided, you don't set it. Does `UserStats` have a `UserId` and a `User` field? The way you have the `User` class set up does indicate a 1:1 relationship on the `User` side, but without seeing the `UserStats` class, it could be 1:0, 1:1, or 1:*.

Comment: Seems like you need to create and savechanges on UserStats first before doing it for User.

Comment: I updated the userstats table with UserID and User navigation property but it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a true 1:1 relationship enforced entirely through foreign keys, as the inserts have to be done one at a time and doing that would violate the constraint.

Instead, you will have to make the relationship 1:0. Do this by making `UserStatsID` an `int?` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your table has a foreign key to the `UserStats` table. If the `foreign key` field is `nullable` then you can use `int?` and put a null there if no value is provided. Anyway, the problem is that you are trying to insert a record where the foreign key's value does not exist as a primary key in the referenced table. Make sure that whenever you assign a value to a foreign key, the referenced table has that key in a record.